# Execute sudo command on Linux from plink.exe on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu, putty

If I execute the plink command

```
plink  user@192.168.1.12   sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Upon typing the password when prompted, I am getting

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>
> Sorry, try again.
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>
> Sorry,try again.
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
>
> Sorry, try again.
>
> sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

How to execute the sudo `command` from `plink`? Or is there any alternatives?

Comment: See also [Automatically provide the root user password to “su” executed using Plink from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66716112/850848).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i know that the question is old but this can help

you can execute plink (putty tools)

**plink -v -ssh -m "path/to/commands.txt" -l usertologin -pw PASSWORDSERVER**

commands.txt:

> `echo -e "PASSWORD\n" | sudo -S cat /etc/passwd`

sudo -S is to receive the password from stdin and with the echo -e "password\n" is to pass the password (and \n is like to press intro -new line- )

the same way you can execute the passwd command:

```
> echo -e "OLDPASSWORD\nNEWPASSWORD\nNEWPASSWORD" | passwd
```

Comment: Though this solves the problem at hand, I would seee it as bad security practice. If anyone on the remote host issues a "ps" command at the right time they will have your password in plain text.  edit: typos

Comment: THX it's working!
`@echo on 
set user=login
set host=ip
set pswd=passwd
plink.exe -v -ssh "%user%@%host%" -pw "%pswd%" "echo -e '%pswd%\n' | sudo -S df -h"

pause`

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a plink here? In general, you'd use a plink to call a non-interactive script on a remote host. If you want to do interactive stuff, (like edit a file), just ssh to the server (either from your shell, using 'ssh' client on Linux, or by running putty on Windows), then edit the file.

More info on plink, and some examples, can [be found here](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

Comment: I need to connect to linux from c sharp code, so i tried using plink. Actually i need to invoke a script. I just given an example.

Answer (score 3):

Why Plink ? use SSH instead. Also SSH would need `-t` option for `sudo` commands.
From ssh man page:

```
 -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote
         machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty
         allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Comment: Thanks. if i use -t option, then for the sudo commands, its prompting for the password. Is there a way to send the password in the command with having to prompt.

Comment: I am not aware of way to send password in the command. In stead, on your destination server, in sudo, you can configure user with `NOPASSWD` option. So that he won't be promoted for any password for any sudo command that he runs. Read sudo documentation for more information on NOPASSWD.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make some folders and set perms. These blocks worked for me in PowerShell to automate. Whoever up there that is suggesting to just use SSH hopefully has figured out that is currently not the right solution. Reduction of manual process should be everyone's goal.

```
$null = iex "cmd /c $plinkpath -ssh -l $linuser -pw $linpass $computername `"echo $linpass | sudo -S mkdir $puppetfolder`"" *>&1

$null = iex "cmd /c $plinkpath -ssh -l $linuser -pw $linpass $computername `"echo $linpass | sudo -S chmod o+wx $puppetfolder`"" *>&1
```